# convert json to javascript object

Tags: json, datatables

Here I have an example consider:

```
{"campaigns":{"campDetails":[{"campaign_id":"1012","campaign_name":"**RP - Axe Sample (Submit)**"}]}}
```

want to alert the campaign_name from the above link,
I have tried using

```
var str = above given string;
var obj = json.parse(str);
alert(obj.campaigns.campDetails.campaign_id);
```

but it does not seem to work , any help regarding this issue?

Comment: Read the error messages. Fix the problems logically. And if you can't fix a problem by yourself, adequately report it - "does not [seem to] work" is not sufficient. Trivially, `json` probably throws a ReferenceError - but who knows "what is wrong".

Comment: what happens if you print obj?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few problems. Let's go line by line:

```
var str = above given string;
```

This is important; "above given as string" must be escaped properly. If you're using the following, you have to escape all of the inner double quotes.

```
var str = "{"campaigns":{"campDetails":[{"campaign_id":"1012","campaign_name":"**RP - Axe Sample (Submit)**"}]}}";
```

(Note the syntax coloring.)

Alternatively, you could just use single quotes to encapsulate the JSON object.

```
var obj = json.parse(str);
```

This should be `JSON.parse(str)` (not `json`).

```
alert(obj.campaigns.campDetails.campaign_id);
```

If you look at the structure of the object, you'll see that `campDetails` is an array, so you have to access `campDetails[0]` (the first element in the array) before you can grab that element's `campaign_id`. It should be `obj.campaigns.campDetails[0].campaign_id`.